# How do I list all the voices available in the libflite library?

Tags: ffmpeg, text-to-speech-voices

Having read about the the libflite library in `man ffmpeg-filters` I am already familiar enough with it to make `ffplay` speak in different voices, like so:

```
ffplay -f lavfi flite=text='Love':voice=kal
ffplay -f lavfi flite=text='Love':voice=slt
```

How do I list all the voices available in the libflite library?
I've tried
`ffmpeg -f lavfi flite=list_voices=1` but I get
`Requested output format 'lavfi' is not a suitable output format flite=list_voices=1: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the
[Armadeus project - Flite](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Flite),
these are :

```bash
$flite -lv
Voices available: kal awb_time kal16 awb rms slt
```

You may also see this list in the source file
[asrc_flite.c line 91](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/ffmpeg/+/refs/tags/n2.4.1/libavfilter/asrc_flite.c#91)
:

```
static struct voice_entry voice_entries[] = {
    MAKE_VOICE_STRUCTURE(awb),
    MAKE_VOICE_STRUCTURE(kal),
    MAKE_VOICE_STRUCTURE(kal16),
    MAKE_VOICE_STRUCTURE(rms),
    MAKE_VOICE_STRUCTURE(slt),
};
```

For more information see
[FFMPEG-FILTERS(1)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ffmpeg-filters.1.en).

Comment: Thanks, it works. In order to run `flite -lv` I had to install it first: `sudo apt install flite`. Before installing it I just had `libflite1` installed and it was enough to use the library with `ffplay` and `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to properly ask the filter `flite` to list voices from FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "flite=list_voices=true"
```

Your attempt was just missing a `-i` in front of the filter, and replace `1` with `true`. Filters like `flite`, which don't take in Audio/Video as input, can be used as input themselves when using `lavfi`. Another example of this is the `mandelbrot` filter; while `flite` outputs audio, `mandelbrot` outputs video.

Available voice options for `flite` as of FFMPEG gitmaster dated 2023/06/08:

```
awb
kal
kal16
rms
slt
```

Comment: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "flite=list_voices=true"` raises "Error opening input file flite=list_voices=true."

Comment: @Apostolos Are you running the latest git master version? If so it should work unless maybe your console handles quotes differently. you can alternatively try removing the quotes or also try `ffmpeg -filter_complex flite=list_voices=true`

Comment: The error I mentioned was from ffmpeg 4.0. I upgraded to 6.0 and it shows the 5 voices. But since ffmpeg loves showing error messages --can't do without them, they are part of its insanity-- after showing the list, it ends with another error this time: "Error processing filtergraph" (when -f lavfi is used) and "Error initializing filters" (when -filter_complex is used). 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Apostolos Yes, no need to worry about those error messages. They happen simply because there is currently no supported way to ask ffmpeg to invoke a filter without giving it a task, and so FFMPEG will return an error message since it finds no task to execute with the filter after said filter was invoked to display some messages. For now you can think of those commands as a workaround to querying a filter without having it do any actual filtering.

Comment: OK. Thanks again @programmar.